# Proving that an alternative sum of factorials is zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, summation

I have to prove that for every $k$ the following differential equation is fulfilled by monomials of even degree less than $2k$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^{(k)}x^{j-1}f^{(j)}(x)=0,
$$
with $a_j^{(k)}:=\frac{(2k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!\,(k-j)!\,(-2)^{k-j}}$.
By linearity I can assume $f(x)=x^{2h}$ for some $h=0,...,k-1$. If I put it into the equation I obtain something equivalent to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-2)^{j}\frac{(2k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!(k-j)!}(2h)_j=\sum_{j=1}^{min(k,2h)}(-2)^{j}\frac{(2k-j-1)!(2h)!}{(j-1)!(k-j)!(2h-j)!},
$$
where $(x)_n$ means the falling factorial or the Pochhammer symbol, then computing initial cases I get $0$. How to prove that it is always $0$?
My attempt is by induction: the case $h=0$ is obvious. Now, suppose that for some $h=0,...,k-2$ it holds $\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-2)^{j}\frac{(2k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!(k-j)!}(2h)_j=0$, then for $h+1$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
&\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-2)^{j}\frac{(2k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!(k-j)!}(2h+2)_j,
\end{split}
$$
but I cannot use my induction hypothesis. Moreover, something has to tell me that for $h=k-1$ the induction should stop working, since for $h=k$ the sum is not zero.
Another way to solve the problem is trying to prove that the sum becomes polynomial in $h$, with $\{0,1,...,k-1\}$ as its roots:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-2)^{j}\frac{(2k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!(k-j)!}(2h)_j=(-4)^k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(h-j)=(-4)^k(h)_{k+1}.
$$
For this purpose, I've tried to compute the coefficients of those polynomials: it is easy to show that $a_0=0$ for the coefficient $a_l$ it is enough to derive the formal expression $l$-times and then evaluate in $h=0$. For example $a_1=(-4)^k(k-1)!$ for both, but the $l$-derivative is hard to compute.
However, this second way is preferable, since it proves that the sum is zero if and only if $0<h<k-1$.
If I try to compute the sum with Wolfram alpha it gives me something related to the hypergeometric function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), but I don't know how to use that information.

Comment: How do you define the factorial of a negative number? For example, for $k=10, h=1$ at $j=2$ you have $0!$, and for $j>2$ you have $(2-j)!$

Comment: @Andrei As $\infty$, of course, with terms in which this appears in the denominator, as $0$. Pretty standard in combinatorics. After all, the Gamma function has simple poles at the non-positive integers.

Comment: I am guessing $f^{(j)}(x)$ is the $j$-th derivative of $f(x)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the derivative.

Comment: Perhaps you have already noticed, but your sum is $(k-1)!\sum_{j\geq 1} (-2)^j \frac{1}{j}\binom{2h}{j}\binom{2k-j-1}{k-j}$. This is very naturally the convolution of two series. The series with the (2k...) binomial coefficient is very nice; it's just $(1-z)^{-k}$ But the other series ever-so-slightly off: if it were $\binom{2h}{j-1}$ instead then it would essentially be $(1+2z)^{2h}$ but the binomial has j instead of j-1. I have the feeling that someone who handles series more regularly could finish this off.

Comment: Wow, that’s very useful. I’ll try to use your suggestions.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I think the $\frac{1}{j}$ should be $j$

Comment: @EricNathanStucky moreover, that is not an infinite series, but just a finite sum.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe I got the $j$ wrong haha. But the infinite series was intentional as it's a finite sum in disguise: if $j>2h$ the first binomial is zero, and if $j>k$ then the second binomial is zero.

Comment: So the $j$ in the numerator does make things much nicer: the desired sum is the coefficient of $z^{k-1}$ in the power series of $-4h(k-1)! \frac{(1-2z)^{2h-1}}{(1-z)^k}$. This does indeed appear to be $0$, but it also appears to be the *only* zero coefficient in this series, so I'm afraid it is a new name for the same mystery...

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to at least find a bad solution, which is slightly too long for a comment.

- By [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+%28-2%29%5En+*+n*%28%282h%29+choose+n%29+*+%28%282k-n-1%29+choose+k-n%29) the sum is junk times $_2F_1(1-2h, 1-k, 2-2k; 2)$.
- By [table lookup](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/05/08/0002/), if the argument (last input) to $_2F_1$ is $2$, the third parameter is twice the second, and the first parameter is a negative integer $-n$, then it is more junk times $1+(-1)^n$.
- Since our $n$ is $2h-1$, this is zero.

This method is perhaps even more unsatisfying than using [Gosper's algorithm](https://vferay.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Teaching/Gosper_s_Algorithm_Handout_final.pdf), although it avoids having to learn it if you're not already familiar. (I should say that I didn't bother running Gosper to see that it actually works, but it seems wildly unlikely to me that it wouldn't. The sum is clearly hypergeometric and, as you noted, the output is even polynomial in $h$. So the algorithm certainly succeeds, and it seems unlikely that the output would be very heavily disguised.)

Comment: That said, I've been completely nerd-sniped by this problem. It's led me to at least two very pretty ideas that I haven't managed to make work yet but am enjoying the exploration. (For what it's worth, I think that $(1-2z)^{2h-1}(1-z)^{-k}$ is a dud, but there is a second way of looking at the generating function that at least seems to be more respectful of the subtlety of the cancellation.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Looking for exceptional values of hypergeometric functions, I found the paper "Algorithms for m-fold hypergeometric summation" by Koepf, where in paragraph 8 it shows that ${}_{2}F_1(-n,a,2a;2)=0$ if n is odd, which is our case. Probably, I will study it further, but for now I feel satisfied. Thank you again for your help, I could never have done it without you!

Comment: @GiulioBinosi I am very curious where you encountered your differential equation problem originally. I believe I am starting to understand the combinatorics of this sum, which I will share as a non-CW answer if I can put together something reasonably complete. But in any case it does not appear to be too routine— for instance, it's not clear to me how to produce analogous $a_j^{(k)}$ coefficients for $x^{3h}$.

Comment: It all came from this problem: I knew that a certain holomorphic function $f(\alpha,\beta)$ could admit only even power of $\beta$, so there is a holomorphic function $g$ such that $f(\alpha,\beta)=g(\alpha,\beta^2)$. To compute the "Laplacian" of $f$, my supervisor used derivatives of $g$, but I wanted to use $f$ and this brought me to the question "differential-equation-solved-by-even-monomials", which gave me explicitly the coefficients to translate the Laplacian. Then, I wanted to prove the equation was solved by polynomial of even degree, but it was more complicated than I thought.